# Ajax posting to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm testing a jQuery ajax post method on  a local Apache 2.2 server with PHP 5.3 (totally new at this). Here are the files, all in the same folder.

html body (jQuery library included in head):

```
<form id="postForm" method="post">
    <label for="name">Input Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
    <label for="age">Input Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" />
</form>
<div id="resultDisplay"></div>
<script src="queryRequest.js"></script>
```

queryRequest.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s').focus();
    $('#postForm').submit(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var URL = "post.php";

        $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: URL,
                    datatype:'json',
                    data:{'name': name ,'age': age},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#resultDisplay').append("Value returned.<br />name: "+data.name+"  age: "+data.age);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('resultDisplay').append("ERROR!")
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

post.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$return = array('name' => $name, 'age' => $age);
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

After inputting the two fields and pressing 'Submit', the success method is called, text appended, but the values returned from ajax post are undefined.

And then after less than a second, the text fields are emptied, and the text appended to the div is gone. Doesn't seem like it's a page refresh, though, since there's no empty page flash.

What's going on here? I'm sure it's a silly mistake but Firebug isn't telling me anything.

UPDATE:

after checking the Firebug Net, it shows that the POST return status is 200, but it returns **3** times of the expected JSON object:

```
{"name":"asd","age":"123"}{"name":"asd","age":"123"}{"name":"asd","age":"123"}
```

Comment: How about putting `exit` here echo `json_encode($return); exit;?>`

Comment: @Shakti Singh: that wouldn't do any good... `echo` is already the last instruction

Comment: Just edited my answer. Have found a typo in your code which prevented it from working in my dev-environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing line 3 of your queryRequest.js to

```
            $('#postForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
```

should do the job for you. Just prevent the Form from reloading the page.

Edit:

Just copied all your code to my local environment and added the `event.preventDefailt()`.
Reload was canceled and serverresponse was good (not 3 times the answer) but i also got `undefined` for both values.

After checking everything i saw that you wrote `datatype` and not `dataType`. After changing it the response in the div is `name: 1234 age: asdf`

Comment: That stopped the refresh, but the result is still no good. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. Right. Single letter typo. Shame on me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the normal form submit is actually happening as well as the AJAX post function.  You should cancel the form's default action using `preventDefault()` you can see how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804946/submit-form-does-not-stop-in-jquery-ajax-call).

Essentially you replace this line of code

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(){
```

with

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

With regards to the "undefined" post values, on the looks of it your code looks sound so it's probably something simple that we have overlooked. I would use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to do some quick sanity checks:

- The URL actually being called (check it is being sent via POST not GET)
- Check the data being sent in the header to ensure its correct
- Check the data being returned to see if you can spot anything untoward there

If all checks out it's probably the PHP side, try something simple like

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This will output all the post values being sent, this way you get to see the data in its raw form (before encoding as JSON) and you can check if your actually receiving the data. Note you will probably have to view this via FireBug once you've posted the data.

Answer (score 0):

You must return false from your submit handler

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(){ 
  blah... 
  return false; // <-- Add this line
});
```

I think your request executes but then it's started again as a regular post, leading to a page refresh. Does Firebug show 2 POST requests? What does Fiddler say?

Note: `return false` is the same as calling `preventDefault()`

Comment: That stopped the refresh. Thanks.

Comment: Firebug shows 1 POST with response status 200, but it returned 3 identical correct JSON objects. As for fiddler, I don't have it installed. I''ll comment again once I see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always see an empty page flash. If you're developing locally (fast connection) or the page is chached then it may show immediately. Use the "persist" option on the "Net" tab to prevent Firebug from clearing the Net panel when a page reloads. Then you should be able to tell whether it reloads.

My guess is that it does reload, since your submit function does not prevent the default action, nor returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It really seems like it's a reload. Returning false stopped the reload.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct behaviour. When you're POSTing the form you are doing a synchronous call to the PHP, the asynchronous call will be also executed and it can happen before the page reloads but it is not useful to do it like that.

If you want to just do the AJAX call then do not use a `<form>`, put an `<input type="button">` as submit and connect it's onclick event to the call with `$("#buttonid").click()`.

If you want to keep the form for people who have JS disabled (good thing) just return false on submit to prevent the synchronous call.

Comment: applied return false. No more refresh. POST response still broken. Thanks.