# stop form submit not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [submit form does not stop in jquery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804946/submit-form-does-not-stop-in-jquery-ajax-call)

I have a form:

```
<form id="orderForm" onsubmit="return prepareOrder(this);" action='@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EpayLogonUrl"]' method="POST">
```

And `prepareOrder` function:

```
function prepareOrder(form) {
    $('.wizard_next_step').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.wizard_next_step').addClass('disabled');
    $('.wizard_prev_step').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.wizard_prev_step').addClass('disabled');       

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Pay/CreateOrder',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.IsSuccess) {
                alert('2');
                $("input[type=hidden][name=Signed_Order_B64]").val(response.Message);
            } else {
                alert('1');
                toastr.options.timeOut = 10000;
                toastr.info(response.Message);
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            return false;
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

The problem in that submit not stoping when `IsSuccess` equal false. For test, I insert alert and alert shows properly (1), but form submit anyway. Where is a problem?

Comment: instead of `return false;` do `returnVal = false;` and, **at the end of `prepareOrder`**, do `return returnVal == false ? false : true;`

Comment: @goldenparrot - Why wouldn't you just do `return returnVal;` at the end?

Comment: @goldenparrot: Why would you actually do any of that? Just `return false;`

Comment: @WesleyMurch - the idea here is to conditionally stop the submit depending on the (synchronous) Ajax response. (Presumably some kind of pre-validation is required, though I wouldn't code it that way.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I read the whole thing wrong and I'm tired, goin to bed ;) Best of luck to you `user1260827`

Comment: @nnnnnn because if it wasn't `false` it'd be `undefined`.

Comment: @goldenparrot - In this case returning `undefined` has the same effect as returning `true`. (But in any case you could always declare the variable with a default value: `var returnVal = true`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Doesn't using `var` make the scope non global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call is returning false, but your `prepareOrder` method is not.
Try returning false outside of the ajax call:

```
function prepareOrder(form) {
    $('.wizard_next_step').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.wizard_next_step').addClass('disabled');
    $('.wizard_prev_step').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.wizard_prev_step').addClass('disabled');       

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Pay/CreateOrder',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.IsSuccess) {
                alert('2');
                $("input[type=hidden][name=Signed_Order_B64]").val(response.Message);
            } else {
                alert('1');
                toastr.options.timeOut = 10000;
                toastr.info(response.Message);
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            return false;
        },
        async: false
    });

    return false;    
}
```

Comment: In case of netsted functions, `return` will return the value from inner function.

Comment: @Pawan - No it won't, it'll return whatever comes after the `return` keyword (or `undefined` if no value is provided).