# Impossible to close fancybox ajax window

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I cannot seem to make it work, no matter how I call the `close` method.

I tried every possible variation:

```
$.fancybox.close();
parent.$.fancybox.close();
$.fn.fancybox.close();
etc...
```

No matter where or how in the code I try to call the `close` method on fancybox, it always returns that there is no object, and that close is undefined. I'm losing fancybox's reference somwhere along the way.

First I open a fancybox window with a simple link
`<a href='".base_url('item/map_view/'.$item_id)."' class='itembox fancybox.ajax' data-fancybox-type='ajax' data-itemid='".$item_id."'>".$item['titulo']."</a>`

Then, from the already opened fancybox window, a button triggers the open of another one (note: it closes the first).
`<input type="button" value="Eu quero!" class='itembox fancybox.ajax' href="<?php echo base_url("email/quer_item/".$idata["id"])?>" data-fancybox-type='ajax'>`

And finally, I want to be able to handle the submit of the form on the 2nd fancybox window in a way it will display a message box (with Messi) and close fancybox. But I'm beginning to think this might be impossible.

The code to handle the submit:

```
$('#email_queroitem').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($("#email_queroitem").attr("action"), 
        $("#email_queroitem").serialize(), function(data) {

        var json = myParseJSON( data );
        if( json.status=="OK" ) {

            $.fancybox.close(); // this is where I want to close

            new Messi(json.msg, {title: 'Email enviado com sucesso!',
                titleClass: 'success', modal: true });
        } else {
            new Messi( json.msg, {title: 'Oops...', titleClass: 'anim error', 
                buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
        }
    }).fail( function() { general_error(); } );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Also tried [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/804958/2600397) ? I haven't checked if putting preventDefault **after** the ajax call is different but hey you may try

Comment: Didn't work. Same results... :(

Comment: did you get the success messages ? ... my guess is that somewhere in your ajax calls triggers a js error that stops fancybox from working

Comment: No, the message is not shown if the code is exactly as in my question. The fancybox error prevents the rest of the script from executing. If I try some alternative method such as `$('#fancybox-close').click()` the message is shown, but it still won't work.

Comment: Since you are using ajax, your called (ajaxed) pages shouldn't have any jQuery or fancybox scripts included since they will inherit them from the calling page, otherwise they may conflict. Also, your custom scripts should be also included in the calling (main) page (your ajaxed content will be part of the main page's content when called).  See http://jsfiddle.net/UDa7w/show/

Comment: Thanks! I'm onto something now. I was indeed loading a lot of js again into the ajaxed calls. But now that I removed it, the `$('#email_queroitem').submit(function(e) {` will only work if it is part of the ajaxed form, and not of the main js file with all the other code like this. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue using colorbox. What I finally figured out was to save the initial call to the colorbox object to a global namespace. For example:

```
globalNamespace.myBox = $colorbox({href:'whatever'});
$.post('http://yoururl').success(function(data){
    // call close function like this
    globalNamespace.myBox.close()
});
```